# Deploying Adonisjs+Vuejs Application in live Server

Tags: api, vue.js, adonis.js

I have a project built by Adonisjs(server) and Vuejs(client). These twos are also in the different folders named server and client.I do send api request from client to server.Everything works fine in my local machine but it shows 404 error for all api request (axios request) in live server.It seems i am not able to connect the server from client in live server correctly. Feel free to ask if you need anything.
Any help would be appreciated and i would be highly grateful.

Here are the details.
Hosted server: AWS
I have uploaded the folder.[image]

Here parent folder has two folders server and client.client is for front end and server is for backend.
[This is my project link](http://crm2.netcoden.com)

I have pointed the client/dist directory and the home page is fine.It shows the error while try to login. 
[image]

This is the error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code? How do you host the sites? Where do you host the sites? How do you pass the API credentials? etc Without knowing the details no one can help you.

Comment: @ChristopherDosin sorry buddy.I am giving the details in comment section